# Science Fiction Book or Story About Dragons

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I remember a while ago reading about a book/story by some author that I thought was Fred Saberhagen, but I can't find anything in his bibliography.

It was supposed to be about a post apocalyptic world where people have lost technology and are being attacked by dragons. The catch is that the dragons were supposed to actually be automated attack drones defending a nearby Air Force base. The title had the word Kill in it somewhere.

I can't find anything myself either because I'm inept or it was a really obscure book. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/edit/ta_search.cgi?title%3DKill+record%3D850

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks. Found it. Killbird by Zach Hughes. No idea how I got Fred Saberhagen from that.

Comment: You might be interested in *The Iron Dragon's Daughter* by Michael Swanwick. It is not the book you read, but there is a thematic link.

Comment: I found that book while searching for this one and it did seem interesting. I'll check it out. Killbird turned out to be fairly short so I read it last night.

Comment: *Iron* is one of the more memorable fantasy reads in recent years...

Comment: Read The Iron Dragon's Daughter today and I have to say it was pretty darn good.

Comment: Wow! You gobbled that right up... I read it... then kept the book... and read it again about a year later. I may give it a third read at some point. :) It's chewy. :)